# Get words from a list in Python and assign it to a variable

Tags: python

I made this code to search for words and put it in a variable:

```
nfo_labels = 'some phrase Horror'
if "Apocalyptic" in nfo_labels:
    nfo_genre_1 = 'Apocalyptic,'
else:
    nfo_genre_1 = ''
if "Horror" in nfo_labels:
    nfo_genre_2 = 'Horror,'
else:
    nfo_genre_2 = ''
if "Mystery" in nfo_labels:
    nfo_genre_3 = 'Mystery,'
else:
    nfo_genre_3 = ''
if "Gothic" in nfo_labels:
    nfo_genre_4 = 'Gothic,'
else:
    nfo_genre_4 = ''

nfo_genre = nfo_genre_1 + nfo_genre_2 + nfo_genre_3 + nfo_genre_4
print(nfo_genre)
```

I know it's bad, but I used to get the data I want from a list(code below), which works, but the data was each word to a line, and I wanted like 'word,word'. I am learning python, what can I improve?

The code I have is this:

```
nfo_labels = 'some phrase Horror'
nfo_genre = ''

total_genres_list = ['Apocalyptic', 'Horror', 'Sci-Fi']

for r in total_genres_list:
    if r in nfo_labels:
        nfo_genre = r
        print(nfo_genre)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than spawning many similar variable names with numeric suffixes, use
collections: (1) define a collection of all genres; (2) define a collection of
genres found in a specific phrase:

```
all_genres = ['Apocalyptic', 'Horror', 'Sci-Fi', 'Gothic', 'Mystery']
phrase = 'The Mystery of the Apocalyptic Loop'
genres = [g for g in all_genres if g in phrase]
```

Printing is an entirely separate matter. If the data is well organized,
printing is almost always easy. For example:

```
print(*genres, sep = ', ')
```

Structuring data well is the key to effective programming: [smart data, simple code](https://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Eadnan/pike.html).

Comment: This is the way, but instead of printing, assign to a variable?

Comment: @Rose Maybe, I suppose. Depends on what the rest of the program is supposed to do. Assembling a comma-delimited string is usually a presentation-oriented step -- something one does right before printing, for example. In that type of context, I would not assign to a variable; rather, I would print it at the last moment.

Comment: I will like to assign it like this: nfo_genre = horror, gothic, sci-fi, same as the print.

Comment: @Rose I'm not certain I understand what you would like to do. Perhaps you are asking how to use `str.join()`? For example, `genres_str = ', '.join(genres)`.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer by FMc.

I would consider extracting the main business logic into a function for possible reuse later.

```
def find_matching_genres(phrase, genre_list):
    return [genre for genre in genre_list if genre in phrase]
```

Creating functions for everything might seem tedious right now, but you'll reap the benefits down the line.

The function returns a list that is built with a list comprehension. This is a powerful feature of Python. The official Python docs has good information about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but the article [When to Use a List Comprehension in Python](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) on Real Python might be more approachable.

To use this in your code, do something like this, which will assign the resulting list to a variable.

```
input_string = "The Mystery of the Apocalyptic Loop"
total_genre_list = ['Apocalyptic', 'Horror', 'Sci-Fi', 'Gothic', 'Mystery']

matching_genres = find_matching_genres(input_string, total_genre_list)
```

It's worth noting that assigning the result of this function to a variable will give you a list of all the matching genres. If printing this directly, you will get the following output.

```
print(matching_genres)
OUTPUT: ['Apocalyptic', 'Mystery']
```

As pointed out by FMc in the comments to your post, this might be more desirable than assigning the string `Word, word` to a variable.

You would be better off using a suitable data structure (as the list you already have), rather than passing a string around in your code.